# No gradients for variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning to train variables in Tensorflow. But I could not even get the easiest case correct. The following codes will produce `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`. Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import click
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
#tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

@click.command()
@click.option('--lr', default = 0.001)
@click.option('--epochs', default = 10)
def main(lr, epochs):
    optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

    v = tf.Variable([0,0],trainable=True)
    w = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,1])

    def loss():
        loss_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(v-w))
        return loss_value

    variables = [v]
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        optimizer.minimize(loss,variables)
        #print("epoch ", epoch, ": loss: ",loss_value.numpy())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is `loss` in `optimizer.minimize(loss,variables)`? Why are you passing function reference to it? Try `optimizer.minimize(loss(),variables)`.

Comment: I added the datatype as Armin suggested and the problem is now solved. I think the error message is not very informative here. Is there any reference that summarizes this type of problem?

Comment: I am not aware of any such reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hi**,
this error can be solved by mention **datatype** of each variable that created.
`v = tf.Variable([0,0],trainable=True,dtype=tf.float32)`
`w = tf.convert_to_tensor([1,1],dtype=tf.float32)`